# Javascript cannot redirect to relative path

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```
function changeOtherEmail(){
  var newEmail = document.getElementById("inputOtherEmail").value;
  var data = {
    newEmail : newEmail
  }
  post_to_url("../changeOtherEmail", JSON.stringify(data));
}
function post_to_url(path,param,method){
  method = method||"post";
  var form = document.createElement("form");
  var hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenField.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenField.setAttribute('name', 'body');
  hiddenField.setAttribute('value', param);
  form.appendChild(hiddenField);

  form.setAttribute("method", method);
  form.setAttribute("action", path);
  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
}
```

I wrote a source code with javascript like above. But it doesn't understand relative path.

**What I want**
if submit form at https://example.com/settings page, the page redirect to https://example.com/settings/changeOtherEmail

**In real**
If submit form at https://example.com/settings page, the page redirect to https://example.com/changeOtherEmail

I tried with HTML tag like below and it worked well.

```
<a href="../changeOtherEmail">Submit</a>
```

Why only javascript cannot read relative path well?

I'm using node.js express module for routing. Is it a reason?

Comment: Try using root relative path without the leading `..`    like `post_to_url("/changeOtherEmail"..`

Comment: change ----post_to_url("../changeOtherEmail", JSON.stringify(data));----- to 
post_to_url("changeOtherEmail", JSON.stringify(data));

Comment: `..` means "move back", so if you are not trying to move back, don't use it. Use `.` instead, which means "this directory"

Comment: Thanks for reply @charlietfl , Prime, Laif. But all of these were not worked for me..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was path.

The url I used that script is example.com/setting. It worked well if I enter with url example.com/setting/

If URL is example.com/setting, browser seems think that setting is filename, not a folder or path.

Comment: It's not a browser issue, for your browser, both ist just an URI, there is no such concept of "directories" in URIs.It's an issue with the webserver, who treats `/setting/` different to `/setting`.

Comment: ALso, when keeping it at `../changeOtherEmail` and not changing it to just `./changeOtherEmail` as suggested in the comments on your question I doubt the / will make any difference. It make sno sense.